# qgis's georeferencer renders my white map with a translucent blue tint, can I prevent this?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, color

I'm running QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour on MacOSX and when loading a PNG or TIFF into qgis as a raster its always getting rendered with a blue tint.

Here's what it looks like before being loaded into QGis's Geoferencer.

[image]

and after:

[image]

Is there any way I could save this file in photoshop or gimp that would allow it to maintain its original colorization?

GDALINFO (png)

```
    davodavo$ gdalinfo color\ key.png
    Warning 1: libpng: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
    Files: color key.png
    Size is 308, 588
    Coordinate System is `'
    Metadata:
      XML_com.adobe.xmp=<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.4.0">
       <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
          <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
             <exif:PixelXDimension>308</exif:PixelXDimension>
             <exif:PixelYDimension>588</exif:PixelYDimension>
          </rdf:Description>
       </rdf:RDF>
    </x:xmpmeta>

    Image Structure Metadata:
      INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
    Lower Left  (    0.0,  588.0)
    Upper Right (  308.0,    0.0)
    Lower Right (  308.0,  588.0)
    Center      (  154.0,  294.0)
    Band 1 Block=308x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
    Band 2 Block=308x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
    Band 3 Block=308x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
    Band 4 Block=308x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

gdalinfo (tiff) -- same blue tint

```
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files: colorkey.tif
    Size is 308, 588
    Coordinate System is `'
    Metadata:
      TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2014:07:09 17:27:31
      TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
      TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
      TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=143.9926
      TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=143.9926
    Image Structure Metadata:
      INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
    Lower Left  (    0.0,  588.0)
    Upper Right (  308.0,    0.0)
    Lower Right (  308.0,  588.0)
    Center      (  154.0,  294.0)
    Band 1 Block=308x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Band 2 Block=308x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Band 3 Block=308x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: Can you copy what gdalinfo says about the source image the gdal commands which are created by the georeferencer?

Comment: This is a much more generalized issue. If I load in rasters to the main map area they are very often tinted with this pale blue color. Very occasionally, and quite randomly, they are not. I have yet to determine what I did in those rare cases when the blue tint did not occur. It happens >90% of the time with me. --- But no, to answer your question, I do not know which functions are called by qgis to load the raster image. I imagine its a very stock command though and that they're might not even be two different commands to do it(?)

Comment: How the *#$^ is nobody else having this problem? I refuse to believe this is just me

Comment: I guess it is somehow related to paletted Images. Run gdalinfo and show us the result. Even better if you could share some sample image and we can try to repeat the issue.

Comment: Here you go. I think this may solve the mystery. Something about the libpng library not recognizing the sRGB profile. I would really like to be able to fix this by changing the color profile of my images, not by messing around with the libpng dependencies...about to add the gdalinfo for a tiff to see if that is any different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original PNG apparently has your monitor's display color profile embedded in it, which is non-gray-balanced.  Since QGIS cannot accurately interpret the icc profile's whitepoint (see the warning in the second line of your gdal output,) it clipping the red channel to 0 with that visible result.

If you have access to Photoshop, open the PNG, use "Edit>Convert to Profile", and select "sRGB".  Then save the image and re-georeference in QGIS.

Comment: surprisingly, this did not work for me. Will keep trying this strategy though

Comment: OK used this answer as a clue to solve the problem. When I opened the pre-raster image into the Georeference tool, yeah there's the old blue tint. Fixed it by going to Settings > Raster properties, and simply turning on the Red layer. You're right it was turned off! Can be simply turned back on to fix problem. THANKS